# Have JOptionPane/parse ignore a currency symbol if the user was to input it

Tags: java, swing, input, joptionpane

I'm currently a student in an entry level Java class and our professor is having us make a financial calculator of sorts. Anyhow, I want to go one step ahead of what I already know and make it so that if a user was to enter a $ sign before the value I ask of them in an input dialog, that it WOULD NOT throw the entire program off. Currently, if I input a value of 10 or even 10.00 my program doesn't mind. But a typical user might input $10.00.

I believe the reason it throws the program off is because I parse the double after I input a string to represent it. And I don't believe that I can parse a currency symbol. You may notice in my source that I inputted a currency package, but I really don't know how to implement that.

My code.... so far:

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  import java.text.NumberFormat;
  class Program1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  String WageInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the numeral representing your     hourly wage");
  double HourlyWage = Double.parseDouble(WageInput);
  String HoursInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many hours do you work a week");
  double HoursAWeek = Double.parseDouble(WageInput);
  
    }
}
```

The project description by my Professor, for the note:

> Using the `JOptionPane` class, your java application should ask a user for hourly pay rate, hours worked per week, then calculate the annual salary.
>
> Then it should ask the user to input a desired percentage raise, and calculate the annual salary assuming the raise is received, and list the difference between starting annual salary and annual salary with the percentage raise.

Comment: Homework questions usually don't get a lot of answers here. Please refer to what your teacher said. He won't give any homework that cannot be done. As a clue, thought, think about what the input type is, and tell the user if he writes something else.

Comment: @Frederik.L True, although I think it is worth noting that he appears to be making an effort (regardless of how minimal) at trying to accomplish his assignment, unlike some other people who have attempted nothing and just want the entire code solution.

Comment: I totally agree with you!

Answer (score 1):

Your naming conventions for your variable names are incorrect; you should be using camel-casing. Apart from that, you could check to see if the input starts with a $ and if it does, you could just trim it:

```
    final String wageInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the numeral representing your     hourly wage");
    final double wage = Double.parseDouble(wageInput.startsWith("$") ? wageInput.substring(1) : wageInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a strong approach to parse currency values, you can use `NumberFormat` to do something like this:

```
final String wageInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the numeral representing your hourly wage");

// Prepare a "container" that will be able to parse a currency value in current locale
// (change the `Locale` if needed)
NumberFormat nf_US = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
try {
    // try to parse a valid currency value for current locale
    final double wage = nf_US.parse(wageInput).doubleValue();
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // if it fails to parse --> Invalid currency --> tell the user
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid currency");
}
```

This basically forces the input to be a valid currency in the current locale of your program, in a way that Java is able decide by himself weither it is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.  The most important cavet is, you won't be able to do it with a default options pane.  You're going to have to provide your own text field capable of meeting your own needs...

You could try using a `JSpinner`.  This has the nice feature of being able to parse the user input and return a `Object` in the format you asked for it (ie `double`) if the input is valid.  It won't validate the input as the user type, so this will still allow the user to enter anything they want, but the field will reject it when you ask for the value...

[image]

```
JSpinner currency = new JSpinner();
currency.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel());
currency.setEditor(new javax.swing.JSpinner.NumberEditor(currency, "00.00"));
JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter the numeral representing your hourly wage");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(label);
panel.add(filteredField);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Hourly Rate", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

System.out.println("You entered " + currency.getValue());
```

Another option would be to use a `DocumentFilter`.  This has the benefit of processing the user input as they type.  You will still need to parse the input after the dialog is closed, but you at least guaranteed of the likely format text will be in...

See [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) and [Document Filter](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details...